# Low-degree "determinant" for non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider a matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ of indeterminates. The determinant of $A$ is a degree $n$ polynomial in the $n^2$ entries satisfying $\det A\ne0\iff A$ is nonsingular.

What about when $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ is not square? Is there is a similar low-degree polynomial in the $nm$ indeterminates that satisfies $f(x_{1,1},\ldots,x_{n,m})\ne0\iff A$ has full rank? It looks like $2\cdot \min\{n,m\}$ is achievable by letting $f=\det (A^TA)$ or $\det (AA^T)$, whichever makes sense. But what about degree $\min \{n,m\}$? Or at least $\max\{n,m\}$?

Edit1: Changed $\mathbb F$ to $\mathbb R$.

Edit2: Thought about it and I guess $\min \{n,m\}$ isn't achievable when one considers the $n\times 1$ case (not possible to test whether vector is $\mathbb 0$ with degree 1). Is $2\cdot \min\{n,m\}$ optimal in all cases of $n\ne m$?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you need some additional assumptions about $\Bbb{F}$ for your polynomial to work. For example, when $n=1$, it ends up being the sum of the squares of the matrix elements, which can be zero even when the matrix has full rank if, say, $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{C}$...

Comment: Good point. Let's assume $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$. Or any field with the property $x^Tx=0\iff x=\mathbf 0$.

Comment: @ lilreddragon , I don't understand the interest of your question.  Assume that $n<m$. If you want to formally work, then the $(x_{i,j})$ are parameters (or are transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$) and your matrix has  full rank. If you want to numerically work, then consider the LU decomposition of $A$; you obtain the asked result with complexity $\approx n^2m$; thus the complexity, for every choice of $(n,m)$, is given by the same formula.  Moreover, your condition about $A^TA$ is very artificial; for example, over $\mathbb{C}$,  $\det(AA^*)$ is not an algebraic function of the $(x_{i,j})$.

Comment: Sorry, assume the field is $\mathbb R$, and ignore the $A^TA$ condition. I'm talking about numerically: if you assign numbers in $\mathbb R$ to the indeterminates $x_{i,j}$, then $f(x_{1,1},\ldots,x_{n,m})$ should be nonzero iff the matrix $A$ with entries $x_{i,j}$ has full rank. For square matrices, you can take $f$ to be the determinant.


LU decomposition involves dividing by $x_{i,j}$ entries, right? So it's not as simple. Also, I'm concerned about maximum degree of $f$, not the algorithmic complexity.